# Know Admin from HMUsers array

Tags: homekit, ios-homekit

I have an issue that When I want to add the room to the Home incase if the user is Guest then I am getting `HMErrorCodeInsufficientPrivileges` error. I have a view which will display after click on the button named "Add Room", My intensin is I want to detect it when the user clicked on the Add Room button and wants to display the alert without redirecting the user to Add Room View. Thank you for the valuable time. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: I found the answer and may be helpful for someone so I have posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally in iOS 9 I found this solution.

```
 HMUser *adminOrNot = [selectedHome currentUser];
 HMHomeAccessControl *homeContr = [selectedHome homeAccessControlForUser:adminOrNot];

 if(homeContr.administrator)
 {

 }
```